# Prove that the functional $F$ on $\mathscr{D}$ defined by $\langle F, \phi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f\phi$ is a distribution.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f$ be a locally integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that the functional $F$ on $\mathscr{D}$ defined by $\langle F, \phi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f\phi$ is a distribution, where $\phi\in\mathscr{D}$ is a test function and $\mathscr{D}$ is he set of test functions.

I'm not at all sure where to even start with this one.  Any help/hints would be very welcome.

Comment: This should just be a matter of applying definitions. Recall that a distribution is defined to be a linear map from $\mathcal{D}$ to $\mathbb{R}$; this means you want to show that the functional $F$ is indeed such a linear map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A distribution is a continuous linear functional $F:\mathscr{D}\to\mathbb{R}$. $F$ is well-defined in our case because $f$ is locally integrable and each $\phi$ is compactly supported, and $F$ is linear since integration is linear. Thus it is enough to check continuity.

To do this, it is enough to show that for each compact set $K$ there is a real number $C\geq 0$ and a non-negative integer $N$ such that
$$ |\langle F,\phi\rangle|\leq C\sum_{|\alpha|\leq N}\sup_K|\partial^{\alpha}\phi|$$
for all $\phi\in\mathscr{D}$ supported in $K$, where $|\alpha|=\alpha_1+\dots+\alpha_n$.

In this case, if $K$ is a compact set then
$$ |\langle F,\phi\rangle|=\Big|\int_Kf\phi\Big|\leq \int_K|f||\phi|\leq ||f||_{L^1(K)}\sup |\phi| $$
so we can take $N=0$ and $C=||f||_{L^1(K)}$.